# How do I replace strings in a template?

Tags: ruby

I'm a student trying to learn Ruby's basics.  I was asked a question, and can't figure out the answer using storage, objects and methods.
The question is online, so finding live help is hard for me.

> A game company has approached you to create an application that allows a user to enter several specific parts of speech.  Once the user completes this task, a customized poem will appear on the screen.  The company has asked that, along with your Ruby code, you include your full internal documentation, including documentary, functional, and explanatory comments.
>
> Here is the text that the company wants you to use:
>
> "Name had a little mammal, little mammal, little mammal, Name has a little mammal, its fleece was colour as snow.  It followed her to place one day, place one day, place one day, it made the children verb1 and verb2 to see a mammal at place

```
Name is Mary
Mammal is Lamb
colour is white
place is school
verb 1 is laugh
verb 2 is play
```

Comment: In general you'll find that a lot of Stack Overflow contributors don't like providing a lot of help for homework and programming classes, because YOU are supposed to figure this out. It's part of learning to program.

Comment: Appreciated Tin Man.  I have tried for hours and there is little to no online help for the online class.  Last resort, and my very first post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#gsub` on a string holding unique placeholders for each replacement.

Note that if you do this iteratively—replace all name, then replace all mammal, then replace all color, etc.—you run the risk of the user entering the same text as one of your placeholders.

To avoid this, use a single regex to match all placeholders and use the block form of gsub to pick the appropriate replacement string.

Comment: I am not sure if the user is supposed to guess the correct input in order for the poem to run.  It may be me, but I find the question poorly worded.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Phrogz said, you should look into using [String's `gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) method as it's the basis for what you want to do.

If you search Stack Overflow for other answers I've given, you'll find several doing what you want, all using `gsub`, along with `Regexp.union` to build the needed pattern.

Here's the basic information you need:

Convert your data into a hash:

```
{
  'Name'   => 'Mary'
  'Mammal' => 'Lamb'
  'colour' => 'white'
  'place'  => 'school'
  'verb 1' => 'laugh'
  'verb 2' => 'play'
}
```

[Hash's `keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) method will be very useful, combined with [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

Comment: I will research some of your prior posts, thanks again for the help. I am a complete Ruby beginner.